# Jquery add input

Tags: jquery

I have `<input type="file" name="p1" size="100" />`

please tell me how to add `<input type="file" name="p2" size="100" />` and so on using jquery add ..

thanks

I am trying
    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

```
$('a.add').click(function() {

$('<input type="file" name"p' + i + 'size="100" />')
    .animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow")
    .appendTo('#inputs');
    i++;
 });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTML is messed up:

```
$('<input type="file" name"p' + i + 'size="100" />')
```

should be

```
$('<input type="file" name="p' + i + '" size="100" >')
```

The original was missing the "=" and the double-quote character for the "name" attribute value. Also you don't need to self-close `<input>` tags.